# Linux:IPC Ticket reservation system using FIFO

Tags: linux, ipc

I tried to solve the following problem requirement:"Build a ticket reservation system using FIFO for an event consisting of a server (a daemon) that keeps track of reserved seats and a client (which can be launched in multiple processes in parallel) that can display vacant / occupied seats respectively can book a specific place.
The system may allow concurrent display of vacancies, but reservations must be made exclusively to avoid granting the same seat to multiple customers."

The inconvenience is that I get these messages when I try to run the program:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EvIDi.png

I don t know what's wrong with the permissions.
Here is the code:
For the server.c:

````
 ```    /* Filename: fifoserver.c */
 #define _GNU_SOURCE#include <stdio.h>

 #include <sys/stat.h>

 #include <sys/types.h>

 #include <fcntl.h>

 #include <unistd.h>

 #include <string.h>

 #include <string.h>

 #include <stdio.h>

 #include <stdlib.h>

 #include <unistd.h>

 #include <fcntl.h>

 #include <pthread.h>

 #define MAX 1024
 #define COUNT 5

 int vaccancies[COUNT] = {
     0,
     0,
     0,
     0,
     0
 };

 char * get_vaccancies() {
     char * msg = (char * ) malloc(49);
     memset(msg, 0, 49);
     for (int i = 0; i < COUNT; ++i) {
         char vac[4] = {
             0
         };
         if (vaccancies[i] == 0) {
             snprintf(vac, 3, "%d ", i);
         }
         strcat(msg, vac);
     }
     strcat(msg, " ---> vaccancies\n");
     return msg;
 }

 char * get_reserved() {
     char * msg = (char * ) malloc(49);
     memset(msg, 0, 49);
     for (int i = 0; i < COUNT; ++i) {
         char vac[4] = {
             0
         };
         if (vaccancies[i] != 0) {
             snprintf(vac, 3, "%d ", i);
         }
         strcat(msg, vac);
     }
     strcat(msg, " ---> booked\n");
     return msg;
 }

 char * reserve(int index) {
     char * msg = (char * ) malloc(49);
     memset(msg, 0, 49);
     if (index < 0 || index >= COUNT) {
         strcpy(msg, "error: out of bounds");
         return msg;
     }
     if (vaccancies[index] != 0) {
         snprintf(msg, 48, "%s index:%d %d", "error: already booked", index, vaccancies[index]);
         return msg;
     }
     vaccancies[index] = 1;
     free(msg);
     return get_reserved();
 }

 void * see_vacancies(void * param) {
     int client_key = * (int * ) param;
     free(param);
     char message[MAX];
     char * v = get_vaccancies(), * r = get_reserved();
     memset(message, 0, MAX);
     strcpy(message, v);
     strcat(message, r);
     strcat(message, "\n\0");
     //printf("message:%s\n", message);
     int succ = write(client_key, message, strlen(message));
     if (succ == -1) {
         perror("write");
     }
     //printf("%s : %d\n", "written: ", succ);
     free(v);
     free(r);
     return NULL;
 }

 void * reserve_a_seat(void * param) {
     int client_key = * (int * ) param;
     int resv = * ((int * ) param + 1);
     free(param);
     char message[MAX];
     memset(message, 0, MAX);
     //printf("client_key: %d\n", client_key);
     //printf("resv: %d\n", resv);
     char * r = reserve(resv);
     strcpy(message, r);
     strcat(message, "\0");
     write(client_key, message, sizeof(message));
     return NULL;
 }

 #define FIFO_FILE "/tmp/server/MYFIFO"
 int main() {
     struct stat st;
     if (stat("/tmp/server", & st) == -1) {
         mkdir("/tmp/server", 0666);
     }
     if (stat("/tmp/client_fifos", & st) == -1) {
         mkdir("/tmp/client_fifos", 0666);
     }

     /* Create the FIFO if it does not exist */
     int mk = mknod(FIFO_FILE, S_IFIFO | 0666, 0);
     if (mk == -1) {
         perror("mknod");
     }
     for (;;) {
         int fd = open(FIFO_FILE, O_RDWR);
         if (fd == -1) {
             perror("open");
             exit(1);
         }
         char readbuf[MAX];
         int read_bytes = read(fd, readbuf, MAX);
         if (read_bytes == -1) {
             perror("read");
             exit(1);
         }
         readbuf[read_bytes] = '\0';
         // display the message
         //printf("Data Received is : %s \n", readbuf);
         char * delim = " \n";
         char * token = strtok(readbuf, delim);

         int client_key = open(token, 0666);
         if (client_key == -1) {
             perror("client_fifo");
             continue;
         }

         char ** tokens = (char ** ) malloc(sizeof(char * ));
         * tokens = NULL;
         char ** i = tokens;
         for (; token != NULL;* i++) {
             * i = (char * ) malloc(strlen(token) + 1);
             strcpy( * i, token);
             //printf("%s\n", *i);
             token = strtok(NULL, delim);
         }
         * i = NULL;
         memset(readbuf, 0, MAX);
         switch (atoi(tokens[1])) {
         case 1: {
             int * param = (int * ) malloc(sizeof(int) * 2);
             param[1] = atoi(tokens[2]);
             param[0] = client_key;
             //printf("client_key: %d\n", client_key);
             pthread_t thread_id_1;
             pthread_create( & thread_id_1, NULL, reserve_a_seat, (void * ) param);
         }
         break;
         case 2: {
             int * param = (int * ) malloc(sizeof(int));
             param[0] = client_key;
             pthread_t thread_id_2;
             pthread_create( & thread_id_2, NULL, see_vacancies, (void * ) param);
         }
         break;
         default:
             snprintf(readbuf, MAX, "%s %s", "you have entered an incorrect choice:", tokens[1]);
             write(client_key, readbuf, strlen(readbuf));
         }
     }
     return 0;
 }```
````

And for the client:

````
#define _GNU_SOURCE#include <stdio.h>

#include <sys/stat.h>

#include <sys/types.h>

#include <fcntl.h>

#include <unistd.h>

#include <string.h>

#include <string.h>

#include <time.h>

#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

#include <unistd.h>

#include <fcntl.h>

#include <sys/stat.h>

#define SERVER_FIFO_FILE "/tmp/server/MYFIFO"
#define MAX 1024
int main() {
    srand(time(0));
    //to generate a pipe to reach server
    int server_fd = open(SERVER_FIFO_FILE, O_WRONLY);
    if (server_fd == -1) {
        perror("open");
        exit(1);
    }
    char my_fifo[MAX];
    snprintf(my_fifo, MAX, "/tmp/client_fifos%d", rand());
    //generate my own unique pipe to communicate with the server
    int mk = mknod(my_fifo, S_IFIFO | 0666, 0);
    int my_fd = open(my_fifo, 0666);
    if (my_fd == -1) {
        perror("my_fd");
        exit(1);
    }
    //my_queue_id will be passed to the sever as
    //the first word in every message

    for (;;) {

        puts("menu ");
        puts("1: make reservation");
        puts("2: see vacancies");
        char reply[MAX];
        int choice;
        fgets(reply, MAX, stdin);
        if (sscanf(reply, "%d ", & choice) != 1) {
            puts("you must give a number!");
            continue;
        }
        char message[MAX];
        char str_choice[MAX];
        snprintf(str_choice, MAX, "%d\0", choice);
        switch (choice) {
        case 1:
            puts("select seat number to reserve");
            fgets(reply, MAX, stdin);
            memset(message, 0, MAX);
            strcpy(message, my_fifo);
            strcat(message, " ");
            strcat(message, str_choice);
            strcat(message, " ");
            strcat(message, reply);
            strcat(message, "\0");
            write(server_fd, message, strlen(message));
            memset(message, 0, MAX);
            int suc = read(my_fd, message, MAX);
            if (suc == -1) {
                perror("suc");
            }
            //
            printf("%s \n", message);
            printf("%s\n", "----------------------------------");
            break;
        case 2:
            memset(message, 0, MAX);
            strcpy(message, my_fifo);
            strcat(message, " ");
            strcat(message, str_choice);
            strcat(message, "\0");
            //printf("str_choice: %s\n", str_choice);
            // printf("message: %s\n", message);
            write(server_fd, message, strlen(message));
            //wait for server reply
            memset(message, 0, MAX);
            int succ = read(my_fd, message, MAX);
            if (succ == -1) {
                perror("succ");
            }
            printf("%s \n", message);
            printf("%s\n", "----------------------------------");
            break;
        default:
            puts("you have made an incorrect selectin!");
            continue;
        }
    }
    close(my_fd);
    close(server_fd);
    return 0;
}```
````

Comment: So what's the problem? What's not working? To get an answer, you need to ask a question. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I'm sorry,I added the question in the code sample by mistake.The problem is that I get permisson denied when I try to run the program.